# Why is Ninject interceptor not called?

Tags: module, inversion-of-control, ninject, interceptor

Quick question - I can't figure out the following:

I've written a Ninject module:

```
public void OnLoad(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<GenericRepository>()
          .ToConstructor(syntax => new GenericRepository(new DbContext()))
          .Intercept()
          .With<LogInterceptor>();
}
```

I've got an interceptor:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    invocation.proceed();
}
```

Application builds, module is loaded, the repository returns entities, however - If I put a breakpoint in the interceptor, it is never called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your methods on GenericRepository virtual? Because your methods/properties to be intercepted must be virtual.

Comment: I Don't think so, I've got the ef4prs Generic Repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Ninject interception relies on Castle Proxy technology... so it can only work with virtual members.

Comment: Yep - I made all the methods virtual, and now it works like a charm! Thanks!